# Can someone view the data going over https using fiddler?

Tags: https, fiddler, encryption

Someone please please tell me this is not correct. Reading [this](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) link, seem like one can de-crypted https traffic via fiddler. Does it mean if I am doing online banking via https, someone who can intercept this traffic can read my account and pin key information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddler will act as a [Man in the Middle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), using its own SSL certificate, and thus triggering browser warnings. If you are suitably deterred by those warnings, nobody will snoop on your online banking sessions.
[image]

For more on how this works, you can read about [public-key cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

Comment: My concepts could be totally wrong, but I thought traffic could only be ecrypted by matching certificate on client machine. If fiddler has its own certificate, how can it decrypt traffic that was encrypted by a different certificate

Comment: Actually, Fiddler will (at least by default when you enable HTTPS) install a root certificate in IE's certificate store, so no warning whatsoever will be displayed, at least in Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 6):

Fiddler requires you to install a special SSL root certificate for it to be able to listen to HTTPS traffic. Once you install it, Fiddler can install itself as a proxy (middleman), faking that it's every HTTPS site on the Internet. In short, yes, it can listen to **everything** over HTTPS, but you need to manually install the certificate on your machine first to allow it.

In theory, any root certificate you install on your machine - Fiddler or not - will allow the person generating it to impersonate any Internet site, so never do it without considering the ramifications.

In SSL terms, what Fiddler does is that it installs itself as a certificate authority on your machine. When you access a HTTPS site for which it is acting as middleman, it quickly generates a certificate claiming to be the site in question. Since the root certificate is on your machine, it will trust Fiddler's certificate and happily let it decrypt everything.

Answer (score 0):

You have to accept the ssl certificate issued by fiddler but yes you can monitor ssl traffic with fiddler. If you dig a bit deeper there are more sophisticated tools for MITM attacks like: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_WebScarab_Project

Comment: not sure if I get it. Bank will have a different certificate issued by CA. Can fiddler use that certificate? Or if fiddler has its own certificate, how can that be used to view data encrypted by different certificate used by bank?

Comment: Fiddler uses the certificate obtained from your online banking account to build a ssl connection between fiddler and your ssl secured online banking page (@grossvogel already posted the technical details). Fiddler than uses a self signed certificate to pass the captured traffic back to the browser, so that the browser shows a ssl encrypted connection.