# How can I intercept http requests which an Internet Explorer instance I started performs?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, winapi

My C++ program launches Internet Explorer (it works with IE6 up to IE10) to display some web page on the Internet; I have no way to modify the web page. The web page references a JavaScript file (using a `<script>` tag in the HTML markup) - a copy of the [swfobject](https://github.com/swfobject/swfobject) JavaScript library. I'd like the web page to use a custom copy of this file which I provide.

I came up with two possible ways to tackle this

1. Write a proxy server which Internet Explorer connects to; the proxy fetches the actual data and then rewrites the HTML so that my own copy of swfobject is referenced. This is unfortunately quite a bit of work, and probably won't work with https. I could live without support for https for now.
2. Implement a [asynchronous protocol plugin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for Internet Explorer which intercepts all http requests. I know that the JavaScript file is always retrieved using http, so I could intercept accesses to the swfobject JavaScript file and yield my own file instead. Alas, this seems to be impossible as well, a [Microsoft support page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303740/en-us) explains

   > Internet Explorer ignores naive attempts to overwrite HKEY_CURRENT_ROOT\PROTOCOLS\Http with a value other than the CLSID for

   This sounds like hooking 'http' with a custom protocol handler won't work; in any case, this approach would also be problematic in case there is an existing http protocol handler.

Is there a better way to solve this than either of these two?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the complexity of your requirements, [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) may be a useful alternative to a custom proxy since it can automatically rewrite both requests and responses and can be a quick way of scripting what you want.

It also works well with HTTPS, so that part is "free".

> Want to have Fiddler automatically rewrite requests and responses, add or remove headers, or flag/ignore sessions based on rules you specify?  Check out the FiddlerScript Cookbook

[Here is a link to the cookbook](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/Dev/ScriptSamples.asp)

If you need to embed it, it can also be embedded as [FiddlerCore](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/fiddlercore).

As @MSalters points out below, the Fiddler's optional SSL interception is something you should consider the trade-offs of before using it. It's documented [here](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) and I've written up a short summary of how it works [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9473022/477878).

Comment: Fiddler looks quite interesting! This made me look a bit further and I found [tinyproxy](https://banu.com/tinyproxy/) which appears to be a GPL-licensed proxy server in C. Alas, it doesn't seem to be portable to Windows.

Comment: Mind you, to support HTTPS Fiddler breaks Internet Explorer's security by altering the certificate store, so it can then launch a Man-In-The-Middle attack. That's entirely unacceptable for serious programs.

Comment: @MSalters One could argue that for some environments a plugin that acts as a middleman by intercepting inside the browser before encryption/after decryption is unacceptable too. Everything has trade-offs, and I agree that the implementation choices in the SSL interception in Fiddler definitely is one of them.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: No, that's far better. Affecting a single instance is a local change. Modifying the certificate store is global state. That's why Fiddler is so explicit about restricting HTTPS mucking to Test-Only machines. On those, messing up global state is expected and restoring that state a normal procedure.

Answer (score 2):

Just shooting down an idea, it's possible to hook the WinSock send() and recv() function in your own process. This is a kind of man in the middle.. This solution has a high complexity drawback tho.

Comment: Ah true, I did actually consider that as well but forgot to mention this in my question. I heard that "live" AntiVirus scanners use this approach.

Comment: The advantage is that is is most probably the **only** solution (the only practicable, anyway) that will also work with `https`. I would otherwise suggest winpcap, but just like Fiddler, I don't see how you would be reading and modifying encrypted communication.

Comment: The main problem with this is that the same virus scanner will flag YOUR app as malware. Hijacking IE via WinSock is just not acceptable.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: If that's true, I'm impressed. Say I'm opening `https://google.com`, which results in my browser checking Google's certificate, negotiating a session key, and switching to an encrypted communication. How does Fiddler (not knowing the server's private key) get in the middle of that?

Comment: @Damon: It replaces Google's certificate. Your browser does not have Google's certificate hardcoded.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, just [translate the URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753267%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Change the `swfobject` URL to a `file://` URL, pointing at your copy.

(You're not actually launching IExplorer.EXE, are you? That's not how you're supposed to open web pages. You either launch a URL with `ShellExecute`, leaving the browserchoice to the user, or you embed MSHTML, IE's core, in your own app. Internet Explorer isn't part of Windows and may be absent, eg on Windows N.)

Comment: Ah, that looks interesting. And of course I'm not launching the browser executable directly. I don't want to leave the borwserchoice to the user either but need to enforce IE here. I'm currently using `CoCreateInstance` with `CLSID_InternetExplorer` so that I have some control over the launched browser. Now I just need to find out how to get an `IDocHostUiHandler` for a given `IWebBrowser2`.

Comment: Tricky. In that case, `IDocHostUIHandler` is provided by IE itself, not you. But why do you need IE? Isn't MSHTML sufficient?

Comment: I wish it was, but unfortunately a requirement (imposed by a customer) is that we launch the "original" Internet Explorer instead of having some embedded browser (and unfortunately they were not convinced when we pointed out that it's possible to embed browser engines; it was not "original enough" to them).